# Named Credentials: JWT Token Validation

Tags: namedcredentials

Does Salesforce offer an endpoint for JWT Token introspection OR a public key endpoint?

**Setup**

My client wants to secure all calls from Salesforce to their gateway with a JWT Token. Named Credentials are setup to generate a JWT token. In order to validate the generated token, there are usually 3 options:

1. Copy Public Key from Salesforce to Gateway. (Manual work during key rotation)
2. Token Introspection Endpoint
3. Get Public Key Endpoint to automate step 1.

**Question**

1. Does Salesforce provide a Public Key Endpoint for JWT Tokens used in Named Credentials?
2. Does Salesforce provide a Token Introspection Endpoint for JWT Token Named Credentials?

Comment: I am admittedly a little light on my JWT knowledge, but for option 1 (Copy Public Key), would your client be the one offering that? Also my understanding is that the actual JWT payload is just HMAC signed with Base64 data based upon a "shared secret"

Comment: how did you make it work ? i am also looking for same information

Comment: See step. 3 option 2 : https://mannharleen.github.io/2020-03-03-salesforce-jwt/